# How can i export frequency tables from rstudio to Microsoft word 2016?

Tags: r

I have tables in rstudio,  and I want to export it to Microsoft word 2016.
I have try saving it as txt and copy it in word but the table in txt does not have rows and column.  I try using "ReporterRs" the package not found.  Using officer package never work.
Someone help.

Comment: It is better if you use Rmarkdown, you can create your tables and directly knit to word!

Comment: I have added additional details so you can see how this works! I hope that can help you!!

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question. You could use `Rmarkdown` in order to export your tables directly to MS Word. Here a little example. You can use `kable()` function from `knitr` in order to format your tables directly to the document. You can copy and paste next lines into a new empty `Rmarkdown` document an see the result:

````
---
title: "Example for tables"
author: "XYZ"
output: word_document
---

This is an R Markdown document with examples about tables

```{r,echo=F,message=F,warning=F}
library(knitr)
#Data
data("iris")
```

```{r,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
kable(iris,caption = "Table 1: Iris data",align = rep('c',5))
```
````

With previous lines on your document you can save it and then click on `Knit Word`. A document in MS Word similar to this will be created:

[image]

As you can see a table from iris has been added. You can add the tables you want using chunks and then format with `kable()` in order to export.

Comment: This was really helpful.  Thank very much.

Comment: @AndiliAugustinus Great! If you think this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side in this answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much for coming through with an example,  it Haas help me, since I'm not an expert in r mackdown

Comment: @AndiliAugustinus Amazing you will master it :) It is up to you if you accept this anwer :)